# Cannot locate qmake in Qt5.5 in OS X

Tags: macos, qt

I installed Qt5.5, but I am not able to locate the program qmake in Qt installation folder as well as in my user bin. I run a find command in terminal in search for qmake starting from the root directory, but getting no results. When I use the Qt IDE I can compile my source with option of qmake, so I am sure the program qmake is installed.

I would want to add qmake to my path so I can run qmake in command line. Does anyone know is Qt5.5 is hiding qmake somewhere?

Comment: does qmake command work in your console?

Comment: Are you using the official installer? There it would be $PREFIX/5.5/clang_64/bin/qmake, where $PREFIX is the directory you chose in the installer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`qmake` is located into `bin` subfolder of your installed Qt; probably, that directory is not into your path (`echo $PATH` will show your actual path); if Qt is not present in your `$PATH`, you can include it; you should have installed Qt inside `/usr/local` (or `/opt/local`); add those lines to your `.profile` file:

```
PATH=/usr/local/Qt-x.x.x/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

(filling the 'x' with your Qt version) and check again with `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 3):

Either in:

```
/usr/local/opt/qt5
```

Or:

```
/usr/local/opt/qt
```

Answer (score 3):

OS **X Sierra** / **High Sierra**

```
ln -s /Users/user/Qtx.x.x/x.x/clang_64/bin/qmake /usr/local/bin/qmake
```

(filling the 'x' with your Qt version)

example Qt 5.8:

```
ln -s /Users/user/Qt5.8.0/5.8/clang_64/bin/qmake /usr/local/bin/qmake
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for those not using 'brew' tool to install, e.g., using official binary installer from qt.io